# How do ripples form and why do they spread out?

Tags: waves

When I throw a rock in the water, why does only a small circular ring around the rock rises instead of the whole water body, and why does it fall outwards and not inwards or why fall out in any direction instead of just going back down like ball which after getting thrown up falls back to its initial position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lunar craters result from the impact of rocks on a solid surface. As the body opens its way down, the displaced material has to go somewhere, and it is sideways and upwards. The boundary of the crater are stable if its slope is not so big that fragments can roll down.

The initial effect is similar on water, but liquids can not hold shear stresses. Any slope is too steep. So, once formed, the higher portions starts to roll down the initial slope, inwards and outwards. The inward part produce turbulence in the region of the impact.

The effect of the outward movement on the surroundings is like a second impact, but now on a circle around the boundary of the initial crater.

The repetition of that process produces the typical circular waves, with decreasing amplitudes.